# U-SQL - Join BETWEEN

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

In SQL Server I just a JOIN with a BETWEEN statement to Explode a time range into multiple interval records.  The query looks similar to

```
SELECT
    a.UltimateID,  
    a.SiteID,
    ProductID,
    b.Date
FROM
    ss_UsageTracking a
    JOIN SELECTServerSchema.ss_fn_CreateDateTable(@StartDate, @EndDate, 1) b ON b.Date BETWEEN a.StartDate AND a.EndDate
```

This gives me one record for each data between StartDate and EndDate
We've worked out a way to do that explosion using a UDF which returns a SQL Array and a CROSS APPLY EXPLODE statement.

The problem that I see is that we are calculating the date range millions of times, once per row in the row set.  This would appear to be highly inefficient and indeed is the main source of time consumption when processing.

I've create a means to generate the Date Table used above and would like to experiment on the performance, however U-SQL Joins don't support BETWEEN statements.

What is the approach that should be used for this?  It's not clear from the documentation if a CROSS APPLY can handle this.

I Attempted using a UDF in the code behind to return true or false if the interval was between two dates, however that only resulted in an error the JOIN ON Clause can only be on columns and not UDF's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why U-SQL does not support `BETWEEN` (or other non-equijoin) expressions in the join's `ON` clause is explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621310.aspx. In short: We want to currently expose only optimizable joins in the join syntax and make the execution cost more apparent in the other cases.

You can perform the join using a `CROSS JOIN` and moving the `BETWEEN` predicate into the `WHERE` clause.

So instead of

```
@x = SELECT * FROM t JOIN s ON t.a BETWEEN s.beg AND s.end;
```

you write

```
@x = SELECT * FROM t CROSS JOIN s WHERE t.a BETWEEN s.beg AND s.end;
```

Or you can invoke the UDF in a select clause before the join and then use the UDF's column in the equijoin.

So instead of

```
@x = SELECT * FROM t JOIN s ON f(t.a) == s.b;
```

You would write

```
@t = SELECT *, f(a) AS fa FROM t;
@x = SELECT * FROM @t JOIN s ON t.fa == s.b; // note this includes fa in result
```

If you feel that you rather have U-SQL do the rewrites for you, at the cost of less understanding the performance implications, please file a request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.